# Get internet time in delphi

Tags: delphi, datetime, indy

i want to get time and date from internet

i used following code

```
IdDayTime1.ReadTimeout := 5000;
IdDayTime1.Host := 'www.time.windows.com';
IdDayTime1.Port := 37     ;
Label1.Caption := IdDayTime1.DayTimeStr;
```

but i get :   socket error # 11004

whats is this and what did i do wrong

*my internet and other things are ok*

Comment: time.windows.com is supported by ntp.org, which AFAIK only supports NTP. If you like to play with the older procols, NIST servers (http://www.nist.gov/pml/div688/grp40/its.cfm) still support DayTime and Time protocols.

Comment: I see numerous _other things_ are NOT ok.

Comment: I heard that time.windows.com had been shut down

Comment: @David: still works for me, though. @Vibeeshan: +1 because I do not get why someone downvoted you. I have tried (in vain) to make things like this work before, so it is a very valid question. (Not that Idsandon's method works for me either, but the question remains valid.)

Comment: yeah time.windows.com is fine, was clearly talking a load of nonsense!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*[DayTime](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc867)* protocol is not the *NTP* protocol. *DayTime* uses port 13, not 37. 37 is used by the *[Time](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc868)* protocol, which, again, in not the NTP protocol, which uses 123 (UDP). I do not know if time.windows.com supports the *DayTime* and *Time* protocols, the most common used protocols to get time from a reliable time source nowadays is **[NTP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5905)**, and its simpler sibling SNTP, which superseded both DayTime and Time protocols.

Comment: So, which `Indy` component should one use? `TIdDayTime`, `TIdDayTimeUDP`, or `TIdSNTP`?

Comment: Unless you have to support some old server using the older protocols, the component to use is TidSNTP

Comment: we have to use  IdSNTP with host : pool.ntp.org  port :123 thats all

Comment: Yes, `TIdSNTP` works with `se.pool.ntp.org`. The code `DateTimeToStr(IdSNTP1.DateTime);` returns `1942-08-05 01:48:22`

Comment: @Andreas Rejbrand try only using 'pool.ntp.org' as host its ok for me

Comment: @Rejbrand: try with another time source, check your Indy version and your time settings.

Comment: Windows 7 (64-bit), Delphi 2009. Anyhow, as long as the OP is happy, I'm happy!

Comment: @Andreas: Could it be you are currently in the GMT -588960 timezone, according to your windows locale settings? :)

Comment: Sweden lies in the time zone UTC+01:00 (or GMT+01:00 - don't remember the difference). Currently, DST is off.

Comment: @Andreas Rejbrand: Actually, for synching over WAN one should use NTP (or lacking a better choice Indy's SNTP subset implementation) as only latency-aware protocol. Never for _simple_ services (designed for LAN environments and way too primitive)

Comment: But surely the latency isn't 68 years and four months (although I have to admit that Internet has been slow lately...)?

Comment: @Andreas Rejbrand: Have any supermassive black holes nearby? ;-) Heh, seriously - i just pointed IdSNTP1 (10.5.5) to `time.nist.gov` and got reliable timestamp. There must be some issue with network. Your Windows cannot sync time too?

Comment: I'm giving up then, its debugging time here: `IdSNTP.pas   FLocalClockOffset: TDateTime;       // = ((T2 - T1) + (T3 - T4)) / 2`

Answer (score 2):

Socket error 11004 means 'bad address". You need to get rid of the *www.* prefix, the correct adddress is *time.windows.com*.

Comment: I agree on this, and was just about to write an answer myself, but then I found that it doesn't work with "time.windows.com" either. Maybe a firewall issue? But shouldn't the Windows firewall show a popup message?

Comment: Hey thanks but other error there:  # 10060 connection time out

Comment: I have tried several time servers, and no one works, so it is not a problem with time.windows.com specifically, at least.

Comment: i also have tried many on the net but none of them worked  eg 'time.nist.gov' ,

Answer (score 2):

Here is some simple code showing the use of the idSNTP components

```
var
  SNTPClient: TIdSNTP;
begin
  SNTPClient := TIdSNTP.Create(nil);
  try
    SNTPClient.Host := 'pool.ntp.org';
    SNTPClient.SyncTime;
  finally
    SNTPClient.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: When I run this with `SNTPClient.SyncTime;` replaced with `ShowMessage(DateTimeToStr(SNTPClient.DateTime));` I get `1942-08-05 17:13:16`.

Comment: That should work. Post a complete example of your code and we can try and work out what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

If you get Time and Date use Indy IdSNTP component and set:
`host: time.windows.com`

and on event Timer1Timer (TTimer component) write:

```
Label1.Caption := DateToStr(IdSNTP1.DateTime)
   + ' - ' + TimeToStr(IdSNTP1.DateTime);
Label2.Caption := IdSNTP1.Host;
```

you see on form (labe1, label2) Date now AND Time now. So if you set Time synchronized
put `IdSNTP1.SyncTime;` in event Timer1Timer.

Comment: Better use: Label1.Caption := datetimetostr(IdSNTP1.DateTime);

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Indy ntp client components with the ntp pool.org servers. Works for me if you have any trouble I will post some example code.

Comment: thanks i found Indy ntp client components but i am not mature enough to use them please post some examples

Comment: I've just tried with time.windows.com and the Italian official time (IEN) and it works wihout issues. Using Indy 10.5.5

Comment: actually, pool.ntp.org is DNS round-robin, so produced timestamp quality varies randomly

Comment: I know but I did not intend it for production code just an example. If you need precision use one of their stratum 1 domains for your geographic location.