# Expired date not working when date changed

Tags: windows, delphi

I tried to create a program with an expired date, but if the date on the computer is changed, the expired date does not work anymore. how to solve it ?
I made it using delphi

Comment: When the app is started, it can check if the clock has been turned back since the last time the app was run, and if so then refuse to run. The app can also handle the [`WM_TIMECHANGE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms725498.aspx) broadcast message to detect if the clock is changed while the app is running. Either way, consider not disabling the app if the change in time is small, which could easily be accounted for if the PC is connected to a time sync server that has to adjust the local clock periodically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Need some more information to answer this effectively but it sounds like the issue occurs because the system is using the device's date/time/clock to determine the validity of dates.

The only way around this would be to hook into a webservice for an accurate date value that is then difficult to manipulate by changing the system clock.

There is another stackoverflow thread that addresses using internet time for these sorts of purposes:

[Get internet time in delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4297242/get-internet-time-in-delphi)

I hope this helps!

Comment: And if you install the app on a PC without an Internet connection, you are basically SOL on this.  An alternative would be to limit the number of times the app can be run, limiting the time that each individual run can execute for to prevent the user from just leaving the app running forever. You don't need the system clock for that.