# onCalculate 24-hours or Date Change in Delphi

Tags: date, delphi, time

In my Delphi Windows application i need to login every day.

at first i used system date (11-11-2019) and i compare system date to stored one every time on `OnCreate` if date is different i call login.

But the system time can be paused right ? Then i thought of server time but checking server time on every OnCreate is not efficient i think as my app launches many times.

Can't use token based system to check as i am using firebase REST-API backed and it's token is expired in every one hour however if i use token based i still need to compare it and the system time might be paused.

How to effectively check if date is changed ?

The inapp time is short as the work is done in 10 seconds and the form may be then closed by user and the next app start time may be less a minute so why call for the server time again ?

Comment: What exactly is your definition of *...not efficient...*? You have rejected 1) asking your server 2) asking a NTP server. I'm pretty sure you cant restart and login to your app fast enough that any server would feel fatigue or even notice you because of that. In addition you have rejected your own machines time keeping as somebody might fiddle with its timepiece. So what exactly are the complete criteriae for an accepted answer?

Comment: YOu need to make up your mind. You either do it efficiently by testing the local machine's time or you do it less efficiently by reaching outside. You can't have it both ways. Have you done any testing at all to see if reaching out would have any impact at all on performance? This should be a matter of a few minutes to test all three options and compare performance - if it takes more than half an hour I'd be surprised. Test the three, see what the difference is, and decide which one best suits your needs.

Comment: @TomBrunberg:  As the OP isn't responding to queries, I'm wondering what the point of keeping this q open is.

Comment: @MartynA I did not yet think about closing it, even though OP has been notified about my comment, just in case they are busy and can't answer just now. So, we'll see.....

Comment: @TomBrunberg and everyone have been trying to reply but network is down here so sorry for that. I said `is not efficient` as i thought it would not. as The inapp time is short (by that i mean the user interaction or the work in app is done in less than 10 seconds) so the form is closed than but on next app start why would i want to request the server time again ? (and the app is started through NativeMessages) and i asked the ques as i read that the system time can be paused  but in other SO questions i read that it is not possible so what is right then ?

Comment: https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-pause-system-date-and-time-in-Windows. here and one other article explaining which is removed from a form now. so the back school idea of storing the systemdate at login and compare the date at every OnCreate, may be in the works though.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the current date and time querying a NTP server.
See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4297419/11329562) for more details.

Comment: but querying every time on app start is not efficient i think. please try to understand my question. thank you.

Comment: When you say "not efficient", how many times a day are you expecting to log in?  And what resource is being needlessly consumed by whatever inefficiency you consider there to be?

Comment: @MartynA as i said the main question will need to login every day.

Comment: Login every day <> once per day.  What about my second q?

Comment: for the second, time i would say and system resources as on slow system i may be difference maker i think.

Comment: The duration for quering a NTP server should normally be in the range of a few milliseconds, even on slow systems, whatever your understanding of a slow system is...